# How can I get calculator output displayed on my Reactjs calculator app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working a reactjs calculator app. It's supposed to work like a simple hand held calculator. So far I have managed to capture and display user input of the first and second operands and the operation to be performed (+, -, /, *) use state and setState. Trouble comes when I press the "equals" button which is supposed to call the function I've called EqualsSign() in order to get the answer and display it on the screen. I get 0 as the answer no matter what numbers I punch in. Here is the code:

```
EqualsSign(){
    this.A=parseFloat(this.state.operand)
    console.log("A is ",this.A)// debuging line

    this.B=parseFloat(this.state.operand2)
    console.log("B is ", this.B)

    switch(this.state.operation){

        case "+":
            console.log(this.state.operation)
            this.setState({answer: (this.A+this.B).toString()}, console.log(this.state.answer))
            this.setState({operand: this.state.answer, operand2: '', operation: ''})
            break
        case "-":
            console.log(this.state.operation)
            this.setState({answer: this.A+this.B}, console.log(this.state.answer))
            this.setState({operand: this.state.answer, operand2: '', operation: ''})
            break
        case "*":
            console.log(this.state.operation)
            this.setState({answer: this.A+this.B}, console.log(this.state.answer))
            this.setState({operand: this.state.answer, operand2: '', operation: ''})
            break
        case "÷":
            console.log(this.state.operation)
            this.setState({answer: this.A+this.B}, console.log(this.state.answer))
            this.setState({operand: this.state.answer, operand2: '', operation: ''})
            break
        default:
            //

    }

}
```

[screenshot of calc app and console log showing 0 as the output of A+B (A=15, B=12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK8sn.png)

Can you please help, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For clarity, the reason your setState needs a callback fn to render the actual value after the update is because setState is Async. Also, all of your branches in the switch are outputting the same log message, this will be confusing when you get your logging sorted.

Comment: I think something else is going wrong. The logic itself looks fine. However I can see from your screenshot that zero that's being written is a number, because it's blue, even though your code is converting it into a string with `(this.A+this.B).toString()`. So it should show up in quotes in the console. Are you sure the code is compiling correctly? Perhaps there's a linting error that means you're not actually seeing the latest code in the browser. Maybe try updating the console.log statements to confirm that you're really seeing the latest code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake is here

```
this.setState({answer: (this.A+this.B).toString()}, console.log(this.state.answer))
```

when you try to display this.state.answer, the answer is not yet updated.

**Try to pass console.log to cb:**

```
this.setState({answer: (this.A+this.B).toString()}, () => console.log(this.state.answer))
```

Comment: I replaced the switch statements with if statements and then used an arrow function within the EqualSign button element to call the EqualsSign() method. This what the button looks like: `<button onClick={()=>this.EqualsSign()} className="equals">=</button>`. The final product deployed on Netlify can be found at the link: [link](https://brave-thompson-6cec3d.netlify.app/)